# JSONParsingException - Invalid Token

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a method that when I send a String (which is Standard JSON output) to it it parses it and returns the section I want. It works for the most part but if the String has a low value such as `5.8244367E-4` in it it will fail with the error:

> com.codesnippets4all.json.exceptions.JSONParsingException: @Key-Heirarchy::root/resultList/result[5]/  @Key::PercentMisses Invalid VALUE_TOKEN...@Position::282

```
public String parse(String json, String key) {
    JsonParserFactory factory = JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
    JSONParser parser = factory.newJsonParser();
    Map<?, ?> jsonMap = parser.parseJson(json);
    String parsed = jsonMap.get("result").toString();
    return parsed;
}
```

Is there any obvious way to get around this or else an alternate approach I can take to get the same result?

Thanks.

Comment: After a quick look in debug mode, the [quick-json library](https://github.com/mkotb/quick-json) does not seem to handle very well floating-point-literals. Given that this looks like a fairly obscure library, if at all possible, you could consider replacing it with something more widely spread and tested like [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (or similar), eg `new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"value\":5.8244367E-4}", HashMap.class)`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The elegant solution would be to define a POJO matching the JSON's structure - let's say QueryResponse - deserialize the string `QueryResponse response = new ObjectMapper().readValue(input, QueryResponse.class);` and use it like any other Java object `System.out.println(response.getResultList().getResult())`. Alternatively you could deserialize into a hashmap `HashMap values = new ObjectMapper().readValue(input, HashMap.class);` and _navigate_ the hierarchy: `System.out.println(((Map) values.get("resultList")).get("result"));`. The examples are based on Jackson but you get the idea.